# Why do apps blur out when not focused on windows?

Tags: windows-10, dpi, scaling

I am having scaling issues in windows 10. The applications blur out frequently. This is not happening in all of the apps though, examples for problematic apps: Skype, Slack, Visual Studio Code.

My desktop native resolution is **2560 x 1440**. DPI setting is **%100**.

OS: Windows 10 Pro x64, Version: 1803 Build 17134.285

**What I have tried**:

- Right click to an app > Properties > set compatibility mode
- Turn on "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" in Settings > Display > Advanced Scaling Settings
- Set custom scaling to 100
- Sign in & out etc.

Nothing seems to solve my issue. If I have an app open in full screen, then I bring up another app for example Task Manager (but not in full screen), if I resize the Task Manager, the app that is in the background blurs out almost completely.

How can I solve this issue that makes most of the apps unusable?

Comment: What is your video adapter and which driver do you use? Your computer model might also be useful.

Comment: @harrymc Nvidia gtx 1080Ti , by model if you mean desktop or laptop, it's desktop.

Comment: In Settings > Personalization > Colors, under More option, is Transparency effects set to Off? Have you installed NVIDIA latest driver?

Comment: @harrymc transparency effect was on, I've turned it off. installing the latest driver atm, I will see if the issue is resolved.

Comment: problem still exists.

Comment: Having the same problem, same kind of apps(slack and visual studio 2019). Windows 10 integrated intel video card (hd graphics 4600)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by right clicking my desktop > Graphics properties > 3D > turn OFF Conservative Morphological Anti Aliasing and set Performance mode